# Lua: Remove field from mail header

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I want to remove some fields from a mail header in lua. Say I have a string called "header" and I want to remove all header fields starting with "Re".

How can I do this?

I tried something like this:

```
string.gsub(header ,"\nRe.-\n[^%s]", "")
```

but it does not work....

For example the input

```
Received: by a;
        Tue, 14 Mar 2012 19:43:29 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by b;
        Tue, 14 Mar 2012 19:43:29 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <x@example.com>
Received: from ex.com 
        by mx..com 
        for x
Received-SPF: pas5a;
Authentication-Results:;
       dkim=pass header.i=@;
Return-Path: <bounce-paypal.de>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Reply-To: a
Subject: b
From: c
To: xxx
Date: Tue, 14 Mar 2012 19:43:29 -0700 (PDT)
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
```

should become

```
X-Received: by b;
        Tue, 14 Mar 2012 19:43:29 -0700 (PDT)
Authentication-Results:;
       dkim=pass header.i=@;
MIME-Version: 1.0
Subject: b
From: c
To: xxx
Date: Tue, 14 Mar 2012 19:43:29 -0700 (PDT)
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
```

when removing fields starting with "Re". The main problem is with multi-line fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
string.gsub(header ,"%f[^\n%z]Re.-\n%f[%S]", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is multi-line fields, first merge those into single-line fields with

```
header = string.gsub(header ,"\n( +)", "\1%1")
```

Do the editing you want. When finished, restore multi-line fields if needed:

```
header = string.gsub(header ,"\1", "\n")
```

`\1` is just a place holder. You can use any character that is not used in mail headers.

Comment: The first command does remove some lines and does not merge lines when I run it? And is there any character not used in mail headers?